# Java - conditionally linking classes

Tags: java, class, subclass

I want to design a system to manage a small baseball league. I'd have **Players**, **Coaches**, **Team Managers**, **Team Admin** as the primary entities that I wanted to keep track of. Each would be classes and have their own specific methods etc.

However, for some teams, an experienced/senior player may stand in as acting Coach in some circumstances. As a result I'd like these specific Players to have access to the methods of the Coaches.

My initial thoughts were to have a superclass called Staff with subclasses Coach, Manager and Admin and Players as a separate class. I'm struggling with to think of an ideal way to link Players and Coaches however.

What is considered best practice when structuring this type of relationship?

Answer (score 0):

I think Person would be superclass because person has common character of subclass that is manager, player, coach and team manager.

I also think player and staff are different because players are more special in soccer team. They have transfer fee.

```
     person
     |    |       
player    staff
          |
         admin, manager, coach ....
```

Comment: Ok, I understand that layout you've provided. However, how would I link players who are occasional coaches as I mentioned in my question?